# Shopify API Transactions - "No capturable transaction was found"

Tags: php, api, transactions, shopify, payment

I ran into an issue that I can not handle by myself. I want to change the paymnent status of an order in Shopfiy through an App. The Shopify API documentation describes it clearly how to mark an existing transaction as "paid": https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/transaction#create

I did everything as it is written, but I'm getting an error message:
"No capturable transaction was found"

The strange thing is that the exact same code used to work in another App that we created before.

```php
$shopify = shopify\client($stores[$order['storeID']]['shop'], SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, $stores[$order['storeID']]['oauth_token']);
try
{
    # Making an API request can throw an exception
    $transactions = $shopify('POST /admin/orders/'.$order['order_id'].'/transactions.json', array(), array
    (
        'transaction' => array
        (
            "amount" => $order['cod_amount_received'],
            "kind" => "capture"
        )
    ));

    print_r($transactions);
}
catch (shopify\ApiException $e)
{
    # HTTP status code was >= 400 or response contained the key 'errors'
    echo $e;
    print_r($e->getRequest());
    print_r($e->getResponse());
}
catch (shopify\CurlException $e)
{
    # cURL error
    echo $e;
    print_r($e->getRequest());
    print_r($e->getResponse());
}
```

The response I receive:

> phpish\shopify\ApiException: [422] Unprocessable Entity (https://proda-hu.myshopify.com/admin/orders/3264737735/transactions.json) array ( 'base' => array ( 0 => 'No capturable transaction was found', ), ) in /chroot/home/onlinema/webshippy.com/html/app/syncback_shopify.php on line 98Array ( [method] => POST [uri] => https://proda-hu.myshopify.com/admin/orders/3264737735/transactions.json [query] => Array ( ) [headers] => Array ( [X-Shopify-Access-Token] => 37c97637d737cf7ac8d8784d3d8ba7fd [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 ) [payload] => Array ( [transaction] => Array ( [amount] => 5980.00 [kind] => capture ) ) ) Array ( [errors] => Array ( [base] => Array ( [0] => No capturable transaction was found ) ) )

Anything has been changed in the API maybe? Can anyone help? Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 2):

try to create transactions as part of order array.

```
$orders['order']['transactions'][]  =   array(
                            'amount'    =>  $tran->amount,
                            'kind'      =>  $tran->kind,
                            'status'    =>  $tran->status,
                            'source_name'=> 'other'
                        );
```

worked for me.